# What features does a graphics adapter need for best performance in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, windows, computer-hardware, performance

When running Lightroom on high-resolution-displays I noticed severe performance problems.

Working in the development module in 2560x1600 pixels screen resolution, even simple adjustments of brightness take around a second until the display refreshes with the new values.

So my question is: does Lightroom support any special graphics accelerators like Cuda or directX?

What features does a graphics adapter need in order to be fast for lightroom?

---

Current PC specs: Intel Sandy Bridge, Core i7 2600, 16GB Ram, System & LR catalogs on Intel G2 SSD, Graphics is 1GB XFX HD5750.

Comment: FWIW, Cuda and DirectX are very different things.

Comment: What are the specs of your computer and how many photos in your LR catalog?

Comment: @mattdm, I know, but anything which might speed up Lightroom would be great.

Comment: @Jakub, I found the speed in the development module lacking since I upgraded my display to 2560x1600 no matter if I have 40 or 40000 pictures in the catalog. It's not about the speed to switch from one picture to another, it's about the speed after which Lightroom will update the display with the changes from adjusting development parameters like brightness. (I'll look up the specs later)

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily off-topic, but you may end up getting better results were this migrated to http://superuser.com/

Comment: @mattdm, I was pondering to open the question there, but thought Lightroom might be photo-specific, so I ended up here. I'll wait if something arises from here before double-posting.

Comment: Your videocard has to do more processing to display the image on your new monitor. Get a better video-card, max out on fast RAM. If you are thinking about dual monitors in the future, get a videocard that supports dual monitors natively.

Comment: Specs: Intel Sandy Bridge, Core i7 2600, 16GB Ram, System & LR catalogs on Intel G2 SSD, Graphics is 4GB XFX HD5750.

Comment: @Jakub FYI modern video cards running dual monitors waste insane amounts of power.  I currently have one monitor plugged into GPU and one to motherboard and it uses ~40W less than both in the GPU.  I think there needs to be some kind of awareness campaign about this...

Comment: @Jakub ps I think it's safe to say the video card is not the bottleneck here even without knowi.

Comment: @Peter I experienced decrease in "refresh/drawing" performance more then once when upgrading to a large, high resolution display. The problem could have been related to my sight being able to "catch" the display refreshing given larger size but it sure felt like the videocard was struggling. @ Sam, Graphics is 4GB XFX HD5750? Are you sure about the 4GB of video memory? Seems tht this card only comes with 1GB. In any case with those specs LR should be snappy. Do you have the latest drivers for the card? How about latest drivers/firmware for all the rest of the hardware?

Comment: @PeterT how can you be safe without knowing? @Jakub, no, sorry, 1GB memory of course. My mistake!! Drivers are most recent, did not help. There might be a bios update for my mainboard, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Photoshop CS4/5, Lightroom does not utilize the GPU for operations. Therefore, any video card that supports your monitor is fine.

Photoshop CS4/5 only really use GPU for screen redraws and (I think) a few transformations. Lightroom does not use it at all.  I suspect that since LR adjustments are simply appended statements vs file edits, that it does not need to use the GPU. This likely also increases compatibility on slower and older machines.

Apple's Aperture has been criticized by its use of the GPU, which some blame for slow performance and compatibility.  I have never used Aperture, so I can't say whether this is the case.

Comment: Keep in mind though, many low end video solutions steal memory from your RAM for video use. You will benefit from having at least a dedicated card that prevents that.

Answer (score 2):

**First of all, you need a graphics card.** If you use embeded graphics or the like, you may suffer.

**Second, get the fastest memory interface possible.** You actually do not need much memory, probably anything over 64MB is overkill for Lightroom since it does not process on the graphics card, just redraw a lot.

**Third, there is no third** ;) Other graphics card features do not help since they are not used by Lightroom.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure that #1 follows, given #2 and #3.

Comment: Unless this recently changed, embedded graphics have a slow memory interface despite using system memory. At the very least, they share the bandwidth, which is not desirable.

Comment: A modern integrated video card should be more than sufficient for Lightroom. The modern ones (like Intel's HD3000) even support OpenCL so if Lightroom start to take advantage of GPU acceleration, you'll still benefit.

Comment: #1 depends entirely on the spec of the onboard graphics - not all have poor performance

Comment: One catch is that poor performance is very relative. For 9 years, I working on real-time image processing and we often had H/W which performed extremely well for 3D but terribly for images. Most graphics are not optimized for images. Oddly, sending the same image as a 'texture' through the GPU interface, sometimes gave much better performance but most image applications do not go that way and it only worked for certain bit layouts.

Comment: #1 check, #2 check - I added my specs above. I'm really puzzled what slows my system. Might try a faster GPU, but which one?

Comment: Honestly, that GPU should be overkill. Try a driver update if it is not the latest.

Comment: Tried the update, there was a new version, but changes in develop mode are still sluggish. I don't want to go back to lower resolution, but this lag sucks for working on pictures :(

Comment: Try to set your display to a quarter resolution (1280x800) and also try at full-resolution (2560x1600) but with LR occupying a quarter of the screen. If both are fast, then LR is having trouble processing the extra pixels in the view. If only the former is fast, then the problem is with your system (OS, drivers, add-ons, etc). You can use the Task Manager to see if your CPU is being fully used (in which case graphics is waiting for data, rather than the other way around).

Comment: LR at quarter resolution: fast. LR at quarter size: fast. LR at full size: sluggish. CPU is max 50% in all three modes (meaning 2 of 4 cores are at full use?)

Comment: You should see individual graphs for each CPU, so **you have** the answer to your last question. Unfortunately performance optimization is a very complex topic and I this it hard to go much further without much more information. You will probably have to get a faster CPU, increasing the speed until no core is maxed out anymore.

Comment: @Philip Goh: HD3000 doesn't support OpenCL at the time of writing, but support is expected probably later this year.

Comment: The Intel Sandy Bridge i7 that the original poster has is actually a fantastic graphics option, and yes it is integrated(embedded).

Comment: @dpollitt, the "fantastic graphics option" can't run 2560x1600, as far as I know, so it's unusable for my 2560x1600 setup.

Comment: @Sam - Sorry to not quote a reliable source previously, but PCMag notes that this chip "...shatters all previous laptop scores..." and is "very capable of running the most 3D-intensive games in the world...". I don't know of the maximum resolution it can run, but it is a very capable card. Source: http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2374911,00.asp

Comment: @dpollitt - **Your source does not support your statement**: They are comparing to laptop graphics and are testing **3D** performance which they say is *respectable at 1024x768* but grinded the test to a *halt at 1600x900*. Plus, that comparison is not significant for Lightroom. I assure you that the 2D and 3D performance of graphics cards are poorly related and shockingly so.

Comment: @Sam - Do check if your individual cores saturate to 100% in the performance monitor. If they do, you are CPU limited and would most benefit from a faster CPU.

Comment: @Itai - I run a i5 Sandy Bridge with the new integrated on chip graphics card right now. Works fantastically for Lightroom. I guess I don't know the details of why it does. I run 1680x1050, not as high as the question asked.

Comment: Sorry to hear you have such a small screen ;) It takes 2.4X times more bandwidth for 2560x1600. While *in theory embedded chips could wipe-the-floor in terms of bandwidth compared to external graphics*, they do not in practice to keep costs and on-die size low. This is a problem I am very familiar with and was my primary professional concern for years (and I was also in charge of disk I/O throughput) for real-time image processing.

Comment: @dpollitt, speed does not matter if the embedded graphics can not provide the required resolution. And as far as I know it can provide 1920x1080 (full HD) at maximum.

Comment: @Itai, no single core is maxed out, all are used equally. But I thought threads can wander from one core to another?

Comment: @Sam: Threads can and do indeed "wander" unless you specify core affinity for the process or thread. That is usually not the case, so your cpu usage makes sense. Out of curiosity, have you thought to check if windows is actually fully utilizing the hardware capabilities of your video chip? You did not specify OS, so I'm going to assume Win7. If you go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution, "Advanced Settings", troubleshoot tab...do you have any configurable options? Are they set for full acceleration?